# PostgresQL Foreign Key Syntax Error

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, ddl

When attempting to create the second table in this respective database, I'm getting the following error message:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "REFERENCES"
LINE 3: master_directory REFERENCES auth_table (directory),
```

Here's the database structure that I attempted to create:

```
CREATE TABLE auth_table (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
directory VARCHAR,
image VARCHAR
)

CREATE TABLE master_table (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
master_directory references auth_table (directory),
master_image references auth_table (image)
)
```

Any reason why I'm receiving that error? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The column should have a data type (before `references`) and varchar keys are *generally* not a good idea. Plus there should be a `;` after the `)` of your definitions.

Comment: @joop forgot to include the ; in my definition, my fault. and i didn't know that the datatype before references was necessary! i kinda figured that the reference always takes the same data type as the original. many thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've left the data type off, but that syntax error is the least of your problems.

Your foreign key references need to refer to unique column(s). So "auth_table" *probably* needs to be declared one of these ways. (And you probably want the second one, if your table has something to do with the paths to files.)

```
CREATE TABLE auth_table (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  directory VARCHAR not null unique,
  image VARCHAR not null unique
);

CREATE TABLE auth_table (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  directory VARCHAR not null,
  image VARCHAR not null,
  unique (directory, image)
);
```

Those unique constraints mean quite different things, and each requires a different foreign key reference. Assuming that you want to declare "auth_table" the second way, "master_table" probably ought to be declared like one of these. (Deliberately ignoring cascading updates and deletes.)

```
CREATE TABLE master_table (
  master_directory varchar not null,
  master_image varchar not null,
  primary key (master_directory, master_image),
  foreign key (master_directory, master_image)
    references auth_table (directory, image)
);

CREATE TABLE master_table (
  id integer primary key,
  foreign key (id) references auth_table (id)
);
```

Comment: to reference a foreign key - does that value have to be unique? like what if the value stays the same throughout both tables?

Comment: A foreign key constraint has to refer to one or more columns that have some kind of unique constraint on them--either `unique`, `not null unique`, or `primary key`.